# Serializing Django model objects: Referencing to self

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I have implemented natural keys on my objects and they worked. Except for one model that reference to itself.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name)
```

Calling

```
serializers.serialize('json', Person.objects.all(), use_natural_keys=True)
```

Gives me an error "DoesNotExist... No exception supplied"

-Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of lists, this would work:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

people = People.objects.all().values_list('name', 'id')
simplejson.dumps(list(people))
```